# Extending ngRepeat array without digest the whole array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When you have an expandable array, what would be the most sufficient way to extend array, without digesting the whole array over.

```js
[].push.apply(scope.table, extending);

.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return function (text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}])
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in table track by row.index"
      once-class="row.theme"
      ng-bind-html="table[row.index].tpl | to_trusted">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: if you use a strong identity for objects with 'track by' angular didn't re-render same objects, only new ones

Comment: then what takes so much time when I am extending the table, it looks like the whole array is being redigested.

Comment: I am using angular-vs-repeat, but even when using simple table, it is even slower.

Comment: try not using the ng-bind-html attribute on same tag as ng-repeat, as angular suggestion...and slow is relative, how big is the array and witch device are running the code?

Comment: len = 4137. I do not know how to bind the html then, because html is <td></td>,....

Comment: I do not want to create a separate directive or even more complicate the code.

Comment: Do you load more data from a web service or do you already have all the data (rows) in the first place?

Comment: 4000 rows are too many to be handled by ng-repeat without performance issues, use some other DOM techniques o pagination

Comment: I load 50 new items every time user gets to the end of the table.